# can i use a function than making new php page when ajax POST/GET is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

using a diiferent php page for delete/insert/update for every module i make will make my php page too much for every ajax i call. like

```
$.post("../lib/ajax/edit-user-save.php",{username:username,email:email,id:id},function(data){}
```

I use edit-user-save.php to edit a module. Now for delete i make like delete-user.php. Cant i use function to call when making a post/get ajax request instead of redirecting to php page?

Your suggestion is much appreciated. THanks : D

if it seems stupid question then m extremly sorry : 3

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible to pass another parameter and use an `if` or `switch` in PHP?

Comment: instead of using url , i meant to use a function ?

Comment: You need to write code that checks a parameter to figure out what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass a parameter to say which action you're trying to use, then check that parameter on the server side and call the appropriate function. Something like this:

Client side:

```
$.post("../lib/ajax/user.php", {
    username: username,
    email: email,
    id: id,
    action: 'edit'
}, function(data){});
```

Server side:

```
switch($_POST['action']) {
    case 'edit':
        die(edit());
    case 'delete':
        die(delete());
}
```

Or you could get fancy on the server-side and do this:

```
if (function_exists($_REQUEST['action'])) {
    die($_REQUEST['action']());
}
```

This will check to see if the function exists on the server-side page and if it does, it will call it. **Warning:** this will allow the user to call any PHP function available from that script, so if there are any functions they shouldn't be able to call, you'll have to either whitelist the ones they can call or blacklist the ones they can't.

The `die()` calls will stop script execution once the function call returns, preventing your script from continuing and re-generating your HTML.

Comment: yea makes sense. but when i callback the data, all the html in the server side page will be called ? isnt it?

Comment: @Wang'lPakhrin: See updated answer. Just `die()` to prevent further script execution.

Comment: @Travesty3 Is `die()` same as `exit;`? Any differences or cons for `exit`?

Comment: @OptimusPrime: No difference. The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) says they are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

No. HTTP requests can only be made to URLs.

If you want to run a function, then that URL must be handled by a server side program and that program must call the function you want to run. You could do that conditionally based on (for example) query string parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a variable `function` that will post what function you need to execute `delete/insert/update`. And on the php page, you will need to have [`if/else`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) conditions or [`case`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statements. In which you have piece of code to update when variable function == 'update', and so on.